# WPF change transforms in c#

Tags: c#, wpf

I tried to change the scale of an Image with

```
MYIMAGE.RenderTransform.ScaleTransform.ScaleX = 1;
```

but it didn't work. So my question is how do I change first off the scale but secondly also the Transform methods, or how do I access the different Transformations via code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Standard caveats around avoiding code-behind apply (though this kind of code can be super useful when dynamically generating animations).

`RenderTransform` is a property that holds a single object reference. It could be a `ScaleTransform`, `TranlateTransform` or even a `TransformGroup`. It doesn't have a `ScaleTransform` property. The simple way of handling your code would be to assume you know it's a `ScaleTransform`:

```
((ScaleTransform)MYIMAGE.RenderTransform).ScaleX = 1;
```

If you don't know what the type is then you would need `is/as` checks. In the case of a transform group you end up with an array. If you know the scale transform is *first* then this would work:

```
((ScaleTransform)((TransformGroup)MYIMAGE.RenderTransform).Children[0]).ScaleX = 1;
```

A more generic/safe implementation is left as an exercise.